# Play Framework 2.2 - disable Ebean at server startup?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

I want to create a demo for Play Framework 2.2.1 which would support both MongoDB via a Java Driver and MySQL via EBean. The needed application version should be specified at server startup - i.e. `-DuseDatabase=mysql` or `-DuseDatabase=mongodb`.

The current problem I'm facing is disabling Ebean at server startup. For the latest version it's recommended to remove the dependency from the `Build.scala`, which doesn't suit my need. Is there a way to disable Ebean at server startup?